# Visa has no CVM List with contactless

Tags: smartcard, emv, contactless-smartcard, iso8583

Our acquirer required us to have CVM for any transactions that reached x amount, however when we do contactless with Visa cards there is no CVM List hence 3F is the CVM Result while CTQ is 6800. Is this normal for most if not all of Visa card to have empty CVM List? Since CTQ indicates that Signature CVM is required why does the CVM Result is 3F?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please read kernel C-3 documentation available on EMVCo website to understand how to interact with the kernel, how your payment application should behave and how to configure the parameters to meet your acquirer requirements.

CVMR, same as TVR are not used during these contactless transactions that are using a different flow than contact. For more details regarding this brand regulations, refer to their documentation like VCPS and TADG.

Comment: If I understand correctly CTQ and TTQ is the determining factor which CVM will be executed with PayWave. However CVM Result in this case by default cannot be obtain by the terminal's kernel, is it ideal okay to set it manually based on CTQ value so it can be included on ISO 8583?

Comment: It seems 9F34 is no longer needed for transactions that uses PayWave as it is not in specification

Comment: Yes, there's a logic of selection of the CVM method described in the documentation as CTQ is formally optional from the terminal perspective, but in general CVMR is completely not used in this aspect. As for value sent to acquirer, you should never manually create data objects that are responsibility of the kernel.

Answer (score -2):

No, for example my Visa card has this value, but it's called CVV2. Notice, that different card issuers have different name for this security feature.